# Import all the different icon files from Icons folder in vue js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, file, import

I want to import all the icon files from  Icons folder, Is there a better way to do it.

Folder structure:

```
 icon/icons/
             homeIcon.js
             BarIcon.js
             ArrowIcon.js
             ArrowUpIcon.js
             ArrowDownIcon.js
             .....
```

and then importing it this way:

```
import { icons } from "../icon/icons";
```

and then after importing all the files I want to save them in a variable like this:

```
const allIcons = { type: "select", options: Object.keys(icons) };
```

and then display in the templates or loop through it.
Is there any better way to do it as the above does not work for me.
Any help is much Appreciated ! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

create `/icon/icons/index.js` where you export all files:

```js
export * as home from `./homeIcon`;
...
```

or -> depends of your icon files export

```js
export { default as home } from `./homeIcon`;
...
```

then:

```js
import * as icons from "../icon/icons"; /* loads your index.js containing  all the subfile modules */
// handle your module object 'icons' how you want
```

Comment: Thanks it did pull out all my icons but for some reason I had to do like below: 'Object.keys(icons.default)'

the icons were inside the default